# Exception in EhCache

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I am trying to create a Ehcache to use in my application. It is throwing an exception

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: No service found for persistable resource: disk*

How can I create a Ehcache with this configuration? I think something is wrong with disk config.

```
      private ResourcePools resourcePools() {
        MemoryUnit memoryUnit = MemoryUnit.MB;
        ResourcePoolsBuilder builder = ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder();

        return builder.disk(diskSize, memoryUnit, true).heap(heapSize, memoryUnit).build();

      } 

    @Bean
    public CacheManager getCacheManager(){
        CacheManager cacheManager = newCacheManagerBuilder() 
                .withCache("symbolCache", 
                newCacheConfigurationBuilder(String.class, Long.class, resourcePools())) 
            .build(true);


        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Bean 
    public Cache getCache(){
        Cache<String,Long> symbolCache = getCacheManager().getCache("symbolCache", String.class, Long.class);
        return symbolCache;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am looking for, I have to specify the location of the disk. This configuration is suitable when we specify disk, otherwise you can use my code without disk.

```
PersistentCacheManager persistentCacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder()
    .with(CacheManagerBuilder.persistence(new File(getStoragePath(), "myData"))) 
    .withCache("threeTieredCache",
        CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Long.class, String.class,
            ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder()
                .heap(10, EntryUnit.ENTRIES) 
                .offheap(1, MemoryUnit.MB) 
                .disk(20, MemoryUnit.MB, true) 
            )
    ).build(true);

Cache<Long, String> threeTieredCache = persistentCacheManager.getCache("threeTieredCache", Long.class, String.class);
threeTieredCache.put(1L, "stillAvailableAfterRestart"); 

persistentCacheManager.close();
```

Comment: indeed, to use disk storage, you need to specify the disk persistence